# Link on Session Expiry Destination Page reloads Destination Page

Tags: php, session

I have a site with two sections, one section is freely accessible (not password protected), while for the other, users have to login with a username and password (restricted).

In the restricted section I have included a session timeout of 10mins for all the pages and this is working fine. However, i'm considering a scenario where someone jumps from the restricted area to the free area without logging out, and i still want to time out this person in 10mins of inactivity before jumping to the free area. For this, I have included the timeout code for the restricted area in the free area, but the problem is: On the destination page for the session timeout, I have a link which is supposed to take the user away from the timeout destination page and to a freely accessible page, instead this link just reloads the timeout destination page.

This is the timeout code I have on the pages (restricted, free):

```
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['timeout'] + 10 * 60 < time()) {
// session timed out
session_destroy();
header("Location: mybq-logout.php");
  }
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
```

Can you help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what I did:

I included only:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
```

On the freely accessible pages, and left the restricted pages with the full code as above.

And it now works!

Answer (score 3):

Try this maybe it wokrs.

```
if ($_SESSION['timeout'] + 10 * 60 > time())
```

If you can't see the changes I just changed the comparison sigh from smaller to --> to greate to..

Comment: Hi. Thanks, but I don't think this would prevent my user from jumping to a free page after 10 mins of inactivity.